# Moving the contents of a register into another register

Tags: assembly, arm, move, cpu-registers, lpc

Here are my defines:

```
/* General Purpose Input/Output (GPIO) */
#define IOPIN          (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE0028000))
#define IOSET          (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE0028004))
#define IODIR          (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE0028008))
#define IOCLR          (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE002800C))
```

---

Code:

```
void put_on_other_port (void) {
asm("LDR R0, 0x00000080");
asm("STR R0, [0x00100000]");
}
```

I'm programming for the LPC2148 and I'm trying to write ARM assembler code to move the contents of P0.7 to P0.20. I'm not familiar at all with assembly syntax so I'm getting all kinds of compile errors when I try to fix this code.
How can I easily move the bit of P0.7 to P0.20 (in assembler code)?

---

Tried this in C code:

```
IODIR |= 0x00100000;
.
.
.
if (IOPIN & 0x00000080)
            IOSET = 0x00100000;
        else
            IOCLR = 0x00100000;
```

But didn't work either.. not getting any output on P0.20.

---

Tried simulating PWM in C code:

```
IODIR |= 0x00100000;
.
.
.
int i;

IOSET = 0x00100000;
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++);

IOCLR = 0x00100000;
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++);
```

---

Tried unconditionally setting the value of P0.20:

```
//IOSET = 0x00100000;    // commenting out to toggle between setting and clearing
IOCLR = 0x00100000;
```

Comment: What compiler/assembler ? Where are the error messages ?

Comment: Trying to find it (in Eclipse), think it's arm-gcc-as or something like that, where do I look to find it?

Comment: Are you forced to use assembler?

Comment: Error: ARM register expected -- `str R0,[0x00100000]'
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: I tried using C-code but that doesn't work either, tried this:
if (IOPIN & 0x00000080)
    IOSET = 0x00100000;
   else
    IOCLR = 0x00100000;

Comment: What error do you get with the C code ?

Comment: I get no error, the results just aren't what I expect them to be.

Comment: Did you set `IODIR` so that `P0.20` is output?

Comment: Yes I did do that.
IODIR |= 0x00100000;

Comment: Does unconditionally setting `P0.20` to `1` work?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I'll paste my new code which tries to simulate a PWM pulse.

Comment: I mean, setting `P0.20` without checking `P0.7` ... can you simply output `1` and `0` on `P0.20`?

Comment: Yes I'm bypassing the reading of P0.7 for now, but I can't get it to work (can't output 1 and 0 on P0.20). I have another project where this works: http://pastebin.com/yPcTc5aG

Comment: Note that an empty `for` loop may get optimized away by the compiler. Can you simply set `P0.20` to `1`?

Comment: Ok, I just tried removing the for-loop, now I'm simply using the following:
//IOSET = 0x00100000;
IOCLR = 0x00100000;

Using comments to toggle between clearing and setting, looking at my oscilloscope there are no differences when I build and flash the program into the chip... Don't really know why "DSP template" works and this doesn't.. afaik all you need is set the IODIR of P0.20 and then either IOSET it or IOCLR it but doesn't seem to work..

Comment: I just realized why this doesn't work after a discussion with my teacher yesterday, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized why I couldn't do what I wanted to do.
I confused pins/ports with registers. What I thought I'd do was simply connect the output of `P0.7` to `P0.20` (which is probably possible by passing values to working registers) but my teacher explained to me that `PINSEL` is used to select the function of a given port and that some functions (such as PWM) can only be bound to specified registers (found in the table of `PINSEL` in the LPC2xxx manual.

Answer (score 1):

On the LPC2148 IO0SET is at address 0xE0028004 and IO0CLR is at address 0xE002800C  and IO0PIN is at 0xE0028000.

Here is an assembly solution, there are many ways to do this.

```
.globl copy_gpio_pin_state
copy_gpio_pin_state:
  ldr r0,=0xE0028000
  mov r2,#0x00100000
  ldr r1,[r0,#0x00]
  tst r1,#0x80
  streq r2,[r0,#0x0C]
  strne r2,[r0,#0x04]
  bx lr
```

assemble this with as

```
arm-whatever-as copy.s -o copy.o
```

then call it from your C code

```
void copy_gpio_pin_state ( void );
...
copy_gpio_pin_state();
```

and link it or add it to gcc (and gcc will pass it to the linker)

```
arm-whatever-gcc myprog.c copy.o -o ...
or
arm-whatever-ld ... myprog.o copy.o -o ...
```

you could also easily pass in the pin number (mask is better) for the two and have it reusable.

real assembly is so much easier than inline, it is an even longer research project to figure out how to turn the real assembly into inline assembly properly (for each compiler and possibly version as it will vary, assembly language tends to be more portable)

Comment: I have posted my defines of the IO-registers in the question and confirmed that I'm using the proper ones.
Regarding assembly vs. C code I was thinking that it would be simlper to just move the bit in P0.7 to P0.20 with assembly instead of using if cases and IOSET's to do this in C, but I'm willing to settle for a solution in C code for now.

Comment: both results will be about the same (C vs asm) if you turn on optimization when you compile.

Comment: notice the difference between my asm and yours.  I am putting the address I want to access in a register then using that address in the ldr instruction (the ldr rx,=number is a cheat to mov rx,#number I am talking about the ldr rx,[ry,#offset]).  you were trying to read from absolute addresses in memory that were related to the bit mask instead of reading from the addresses of the peripherals.  One of those addresses is flash memory the other is in an undefined address space I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the ASM code, I'll implement it once I get the C code to work. At the moment I'm having trouble reading the output of P0.20 but I'll take a look at your code once that's settled.
Also as you said, I may not have to use the ASM code as the C compiler optimizes the code for me (thanks for the tip!)

Comment: before you can do any of this you need to at least configure the pins as inputs or outputs.  dont remember for that part if you have to enable clocks or release a reset for the gpio block or not, each vendor and implementation is a little different.

Comment: you also want to be careful using unsigned long that might result in 64 bit not 32 bit depending on which generation of compiler you are using.  you can let the compiler tell you with code line if(sizeof(unsigned long)==4) blah; and if it tells you that is unreachable code, there you go.  or just disassemble and look at what it is generating, you definitely do not want to be writing or reading those values 64 bits at a time and a 64 bit access to address 0x...C will give you a fault (not on a 64 bit boundary 0x4 also not on a 64 bit boundary).